# como cerrar varios JFrame desde un evento?

Tags: java, eventos, mouse

estoy siguiendo un tutorial de java en youtube pero yo lo hago a mi modo, en este tutorial sobre eventos se crean frames cada que se presiona el boton NUEVO, pero se supone que se debe tener un boton llamado CERRAR que deberia cerrar todos los frames anteriores, claro exeptuando el principal,

creo que en mis palabras, necesito algun evento o alguna clase que finalice las instancias de otra clase?? o algo asi, tengo esto:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class MultiplesOyentes {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        FramePrincipal FP1 = new FramePrincipal();
        FP1.setJF1();

    }

}

class MULOYE extends JFrame{
    int Contador;
    public MULOYE(){
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("JFrame"+Contador);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setBounds(10*Contador,0,100,80);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }  
}

class EliminarFrames extends JFrame{//clase para probar una teoria, NO sirvio
    public EliminarFrames(){
       dispose();
    }

}
class FramePrincipal{
JFrame JF1 = new JFrame();
JButton JB1 = new JButton ("NUEVO"); 
JButton JB2 = new JButton ("CERRAR TODOS"); 

public void setJF1(){
JF1.setLayout(null);
JF1.setTitle("JFrame");
JF1.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
JF1.setBounds(0,0,1000,800);
JF1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
JF1.setVisible(true);
JB1.setBounds(400, 100, 200, 100);
JF1.add(JB1);
JB2.setBounds(700, 100, 200, 100);
JF1.add(JB2);
JB1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        MULOYE MO1=new MULOYE();
        MO1.Contador+=1;
        //System.out.println("si existo carajo!");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
});
JB2.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    //EliminarFrames EF1=new EliminarFrames(); //NO HACE NADA
    //aqui debe ir algun metodo que elimine los frames


    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {  
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
});

}
}
```

pd. no me molesta eliminar el constructor y crear cada frame de otra manera, pero no imagino como, con arrays tal vez pero es algo mega laborioso,cuando un simple constructor puede crearlo cada vez que se le invoca.

pd2: por que no se cambia el nombre ni medidas de mis frames? ya meti la variable contador, la saque, la puse privada, y nada.
pd3. porfa corriganme cualquier error que pueda tener, por ejemplo se que la gran mayoria en lugar de jf1. algo simplemente usan extends JFrame y ahi como en mi constructor les deja hacer todos los metodos.

Comment: Al crear un nuevo componente desde el componente "x" sólo debes pasarle en el constructor dicho componente, de esa manera, en el componente "y", tienes acceso a la dirección de memoria de la "x". Si has trabajado con objetos en java, es exactamente igual que siempre.

Answer (score 0):

Crear una **arrayList** que contenga referencias a los JFrames secuandarios creados no es tan laborioso. De esta manera, cuando presionas el boton de **cerrar**, solo **debes hacer un recorrido por dicha array y enviar a cada JFrame un evento para que se cierre**.

El código queda a sí:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class MultiplesOyentes {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        FramePrincipal FP1 = new FramePrincipal();
        FP1.setJF1();

    }

}

class MULOYE extends JFrame{
    int Contador;
    public MULOYE(){
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("JFrame"+Contador);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setBounds(10*Contador,0,100,80);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }  
}

class EliminarFrames extends JFrame{//clase para probar una teoria, NO sirvio
    public EliminarFrames(){
       dispose();
    }

}
class FramePrincipal{
    ArrayList<JFrame> seconadryFrames = new ArrayList<JFrame>(); 
    JFrame JF1 = new JFrame();
    JButton JB1 = new JButton ("NUEVO"); 
    JButton JB2 = new JButton ("CERRAR TODOS"); 

    public void setJF1(){

        JF1.setLayout(null);
        JF1.setTitle("JFrame");
        JF1.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        JF1.setBounds(0,0,1000,800);
        JF1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JF1.setVisible(true);
        JB1.setBounds(400, 100, 200, 100);
        JF1.add(JB1);
        JB2.setBounds(700, 100, 200, 100);
        JF1.add(JB2);
        JB1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                MULOYE MO1=new MULOYE();
                MO1.Contador+=1;
                MO1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                seconadryFrames.add(MO1);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }




                //System.out.println("si existo carajo!");
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
        JB2.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){


            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //EliminarFrames EF1=new EliminarFrames(); //NO HACE NADA
                //aqui debe ir algun metodo que elimine los frames
                for (JFrame jframe: seconadryFrames) {
                    jframe.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(jframe, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                    System.out.println("hola");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {  
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

PD: Ojo al **detalle** del MO1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
Si no lo haces se cerrarán todos los JFrame creados al cerrar cualquiera de ellos.

saludos